# Pushing and Committing to Multiple Branches on Github

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am using Github and Github Pages to make a project website. I have made a new branch called "gh-pages" to use Github Pages. I am new to Git and Github so how could I commit and push to both master and gh-pages branch? Thanks.

By the way, I have seen other responses that mention git cloning twice locally and using one for the different branches. I am looking for a way to commit and push to both branches without double cloning.

Answer (score 3):

To push both the `master` and the `gh-pages` branch to the server with a single command, you can do

```
git push origin master gh-pages
```

You can tell git to always do this when pushing to `origin` by adding it to your configuration:

```
git config --add remote.origin.push master
git config --add remote.origin.push gh-pages
```

After these configuration commands, simply running

```
git push
```

will automatically push `master` and `gh-pages` to origin.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.

Comment: Hi, I tried this out after running git add and git commit, but I got this error: `error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/nikhilnd/whereimfrompoem.git'` The "whereimfrompoem" part is the name of my project.

Comment: @Nikhil The error message says that you don't have a branch called `gh-pages` yet, while you claim in your post that you have already created a branch with that name.  Without further information, I'd guess that you actually haven't created the `gh-pages` branch so far.